# Trying to imitate the grep function in Python but how can I make it support multiple flags?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to imitate what the linux grep command does. This is what I have so far

```
import re
import os

x = input("grep flag pattern file").replace('"', '') .split()

if ("-n" in x):
    with open(x[len(x)-1]) as myFile:
        for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
            if (x[len(x)-2] in line):
                print ('found at line:', num)

if ("-l" in x):
    for file in os.listdir():
        with open(file) as myFile:
            for line in myFile:
                 if (re.search(x[2], line)):
                    print(file)

if ("-i" in x):
    with open(x[len(x)-1]) as myFile:
         for line in myFile:
            if (re.search(x[len(x)-2],line,re.IGNORECASE)):
                print(line.rstrip("\n"))

if ("-v" in x):
    with open(x[len(x)-1]) as myFile:
         for line in myFile:
            if (x[len(x)-2] not in line):
                print(line.rstrip("\n"))

if ("-x" in x):
   with open(x[len(x)-1]) as myFile:
        for line in myFile:
            if (re.match(x[len(x)-2].replace("_"," "), line)):
                print(line.rstrip("\n"))

if ("-n" not in x and "-l" not in x and "-i" not in x and "-v" not in x and "-x" not in x):
    with open(x[2]) as myFile:
        for line in myFile:
            if (re.search(x[1], line)):
                print(line.rstrip("\n"))
```

It works if I only use one flag (e.g. "-n"), but if I have multiple flags (e.g. "-n" "-i"), it does it separately.

Basically what I want to happen is if I input grep -i -v "kaneki" unravel.txt

It will output

```
Oshiete oshiete yo sono shikumi wo
Boku no naka ni dare ga iru no?
Kowareta kowareta yo kono sekai de
Kimi ga warau nanimo miezu ni

#TokyoGhoul
```

When my original text file is:

```
Oshiete oshiete yo sono shikumi wo
Boku no naka ni dare ga iru no?
Kowareta kowareta yo kono sekai de
Kimi ga warau nanimo miezu ni

I LOVE KEN KANEKI <3

#TokyoGhoul
```

Is there a built-in function that can do this? or do you have any ideas how I can do it?

These are the flags:

```
n = prints number line of each matching
l = prints name of text files that has the pattern 
i = case-insensitive comparison
v = prints the lines that doesn't have the pattern 
x = prints entire line that match
```

Comment: You should look into using the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module

Comment: Okay! It looks really complicated sniff but thanks! I'll try to understand it haha @@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, it sounds like you could use an example of how to apply `argparse` to your code.  This will implement the `-i` and `-n` options, allowing them to be specified independently.  This should be enough to get you started.

```
import argparse
import re

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

# basic minimum
parser.add_argument("-n", action="store_true")

# give this one a long name and a help string
parser.add_argument("-i", "--ignore-case", 
                    action="store_true", help="case insensitive")

parser.add_argument("pattern")
parser.add_argument("filename")

x = input("grep flag pattern file ").replace('"', '').split()
args = parser.parse_args(x)

if args.ignore_case:
    flags = re.IGNORECASE
else:
    flags = 0

with open(args.filename) as myFile:
    for num, line in enumerate(myFile):
        if re.search(args.pattern, line, flags):
            if args.n:
                print("found at line ", num)
            else:
                print(line.rstrip("\n"))
```

The *usual* way in which `parse_args` would be used would be with command-line options to your script. If you replace

```
x = input("grep flag pattern file ").replace('"', '').split()
args = parser.parse_args(x)
```

with

```
args = parser.parse_args(x)
```

then instead of prompting for the input, you would run your script using for example:

```
python myscript.py -i mypattern myfile
```

and you can also do:

```
python myscript.py --help
```

to get a help message such as:

```
usage: myscript.py [-h] [-n] [-i] pattern filename

positional arguments:
  pattern
  filename

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  -n
  -i, --ignore-case  case insensitive    <=== help string you put in your code
```

Note that it is usually tidiest to put all the argument parsing code into a function, which sets up the parser and returns the argument dictionary.  Going back to your initial example with argument list `x`, this might look like:

```
def parse_my_args(x):
    parser = ......
    parser.add_argument(.....)
    ... etc ...
    return parser.parse_args(x)

x = .......
args = parse_my_args(x)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!! But I have a question,  what does this do?  Why is this the condition? if re.search(args.pattern, line, flags):

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the full print for each flag.  I think you need to rethink the strategy.  I wrote up a simplified version here (taking some liberties as I don't have your files to work with).

Basically I broke it up into different logical pieces, a set-everything-up stage then a test-all-the-lines phase.  I hope it gives you some ideas to mull over!

```
import re
import os

file_lines = [
  'Oshiete oshiete yo sono shikumi wo',
  'Boku no naka ni dare ga iru no?',
  'Kowareta kowareta yo kono sekai de',
  'Kimi ga warau nanimo miezu ni',
  'I LOVE KEN KANEKI <3',
]


x = input("grep flag pattern file: ").replace('"', '') .split()

flags = [word for word in x if word[0] == '-']
subject = x[len(x)-2]
filename = x[len(x)-1]
show_line_numbers = False
line_by_line_checks = []

# check for case insenstive
# force everything to be lower case
if '-i' in flags:
    subject = subject.lower()
    file_lines = [l.lower() for l in file_lines]

if '-n' in flags:
  show_line_numbers = True

# line by line checks
# create more line by line checks if you want
if '-v' in flags:
  line_by_line_checks.append(lambda a : subject not in a)
else:
  line_by_line_checks.append(lambda a : subject in a)

# loop through the lines and see what passes
lines_to_return = {}
for i in range(0, len(file_lines)):
  line = file_lines[i]
  line_passes = False
  for func in line_by_line_checks:
    if func(line):
      line_passes = True
  if line_passes:
    lines_to_return[i] = line

# now you have a dictionary
# the key is the line number
# if the dictionary is empty the file did not pass
# {
#   2: 'Kowareta kowareta yo kono sekai de',
#   4: 'I LOVE KEN KANEKI <3',
# }

# and print out some kind of output
if not bool(lines_to_return):
  print('"{}" did not contain the search pattern'.format(filename))
else:
  for key in lines_to_return:
    if show_line_numbers:
      print("{} {}".format(key, lines_to_return[key]))
    else:
      print(lines_to_return[key])
```

A few tests:

grep flag pattern file: -v kaneki filename.txt

```
Oshiete oshiete yo sono shikumi wo
Boku no naka ni dare ga iru no?
Kowareta kowareta yo kono sekai de
Kimi ga warau nanimo miezu ni
I LOVE KEN KANEKI <3
```

grep flag pattern file: -i -v kaneki filename.txt

```
oshiete oshiete yo sono shikumi wo
boku no naka ni dare ga iru no?
kowareta kowareta yo kono sekai de
kimi ga warau nanimo miezu ni
```

grep flag pattern file: -n -i -v "sekai" filename.txt

```
0 oshiete oshiete yo sono shikumi wo
1 boku no naka ni dare ga iru no?
3 kimi ga warau nanimo miezu ni
4 i love ken kaneki <3
```

grep flag pattern file: -n -i "sekai" filename.txt

```
2 kowareta kowareta yo kono sekai de
```

Comment: This is great!! But what does func(line) do here?                                                        
 for func in line_by_line_checks:
    if func(line):
      line_passes = True

Comment: `line_by_line_checks` is a list of functions to be performed on each line, each function should return a boolean.  If you haven't ever seen this kind of thing before I would suggest reading up on `lambda` functions in python.  They're basically inline functions that return their expression `a = lambda x : 2+2 == 4; a()` will return true.  Look at the `if '-v' in flags:` section, you'll see a comment about adding any other line by line checks you might need. `func(line)` is calling those lambda functions and giving the line as the parameter to the function created in the `-v` section.

Comment: I made a typo in my example lambda (I didn't hand in the argument for `x`) `a = lambda x : 2+x == 4; print(a(2))` which is equivalent to this JavaScript code `var a = function(x) { return 2+x == 4 }` and in lambda syntax `var a = (x) => { return 2+x == 4 }` or even simpler `var a = (x) => 2+x == 4`