# Why is the variable not updated? Function problem

Tags: python-3.x, function

Trying to use functions for the first time! But I'm having a problem with the variables. Why is it not updated?

```
def errorcheck(var):
        while (var != "y" and var != "n"):
                var = input("\nError. Input Y or n only. Enter again:\n-> ").lower() #gives user a choice on what directory
        return var

def getdirectory():
    print("\nCurrent directory is: " + os.getcwd()) #print current directory
    choice2 = input("\nRename files in current directory? Y or n:\n-> ").lower() #gives user a choice on what directory
    errorcheck(choice2)
    print("Choice 2 is now:" + choice2)
```

I'm expecting choice 2's value will change after errorcheck but choice 2 is still the same value as what was inputted before the errorcheck.

```
Rename files in current directory? Y or n:
-> hello

Error. Input Y or n only. Enter again:
-> n
Choice 2 is now: hello
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: You don't use the return value of the function. You just ignore it

Comment: Hi! What do you mean? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the errorcheck function returns a value, you're not using it.
Change the second function to:

```
def getdirectory():
    print("Choice 2 is now:" + errorcheck(choice2))
    choice2 = input("\nRename files in current directory? Y or n:\n-> ").lower()
    choice2 = errorcheck(choice2) #Update choice2
    print("Choice 2 is now:" + choice2)
```

Functions can't change the values of variables outside of them. In some other languages, you can do this with *pointers*, but Python cannot use these. To do that, you have to return the value, then update the variable with the return value.

Comment: Hi! It gets updated now. But I have to input n or y TWICE before getting out the loop :< Why is this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - it works for me. Have you removed the first time you called `errorcheck(choice2)`? The print function should go right after the input.

Comment: I've added a little bit more information about why this works, and why yours didn't. That kind of stuff tripped me up too when I started programming.

Comment: Yea.. I only started programming for a month. I have another "newbie" question you might want to answer haha it's my comment on the first answer here! https://stackoverflow.com/q/62964187/13764026  I'm having trouble understanding the if else logic behind it

Comment: Sorry - I don't have much experience with the _re_ library, but the only thing I really can do is point you to some documentation: [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#), [Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp), [RegExp tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)